# using exec(); in PHP with variables

Tags: php, arrays, debian

I'm trying to execute a command on a local Debian server. The code is as following;

```
if (isset($INPUTdifference)) {


    $counter = count($INPUTdifference);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {

        $pkts = $INPUTdifference[$i]["pkts"];
        $bytes = $INPUTdifference[$i]["bytes"];
        $target = $INPUTdifference[$i]["target"];     // = -j 
        $prot = $INPUTdifference[$i]["prot"];        // = -p
        $opt = $INPUTdifference[$i]["opt"];
        $in = $INPUTdifference[$i]["in"];            // = -i
        $out = $INPUTdifference[$i]["out"];         // = -o
        $source = $INPUTdifference[$i]["source"];   // = -s
        $destination = $INPUTdifference[$i]["destination"]; // -d
        //Filter results

        $badOpt;
        if (strcmp($opt, $badOpt)) {
            $opt = "all";
            return $opt;
        }

        // Execute command with parameters acquired from array
        exec("sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j $target -p $prot -i $in -o $out -s $source -d $destination ");
        echo 'complete yo';
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use values from the Array into my `exec` call. The values are all tested and get parsed correctly.

I try to execute the command, and it doesn't give me any feedback/results on the server. At first it was cussing about how I didn't get a parameter right, but I fixed that. So it -is- getting executed on the server. That, I guess, narrows it down to the syntax itself... am I missing something here?

Comment: your user is a sudoer, right? How do you provide password to sudo?

Comment: `exec("sudo ...` <- This means you have given PHP sudo privileges; I would highly recommend you rethink this approach and, if actually necessary, use `sudo` to execute this PHP script instead.

Comment: Hi both, security is no issue here since I'm practicing, but thanks a lot for the tip. Noted down for research later.

@M.C.  Is it necessary if this script gets executed on the server itself through a sudo command line?

Comment: if you are executing PHP script with sudo, then again re-doing sudo maybe causing the problem. Try it without sudo in PHP, just execute PHP script with sudo, not inside code

Comment: Looks insanely dangerous... really: sudo + unsanitized variable values passed to exec! ouch

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem It is good sir, but I'd like to see if my idea works out first :-)

Comment: *"security is no issue here since I'm practicing"* ... it's quite obvious from your code that security is **very much** an issue for you. Don't ever do this.

Comment: @rdrowley It's an experiment for me, local sandbox and doesn't get **anywhere near** any commercial instance or something where it could influence work. I'm aware of it and I'm just looking for what's wrong here. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put direct /path/to/sudo instead of just sudo. exec don't appreciate sometimes to find out the path by itself.